# Topic Correlation Analysis for Cross-Domain Text Classification using Python [or R]

Tags: nlp, pyldavis

do you have any pointers on how to perform NLP topic correlation with Python. I have used pyLDAvis for a visual topic correlation but am unable to find a method to get the correlation in tabular format?

Below is a reference link to the subject to make it clearer: https://towardsdatascience.com/end-to-end-topic-modeling-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-35ce4ed6b3e0

Thank you!